# Can you use a DDNS service to have a static "connection from address"?

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, ip, dynamic-dns

Im familiar with using a DDNS service like dyn or noip.com to map a "static" memorable address to a dynamic IP address, which allows you to access a router / device for VPN,  viewign CCTV etc. If that locaiton only has a dynamic IP.

But am i able to use a DDNS service in reverse if another service im connecting to requires me to have a static IP as part of it authentication process.

Eg. some web servers can have a lock on the FTP login that not only requires a username and password, but also requires you to be logging in from a select IP (or range of IPs).

But if you have a dynamic public IP address is there a way you can use a DDNS service to give / mask your dynamic public IP address a "static" address so that services can see you are connecting from a pre approved connection address ?

Comment: You would have to use a VPN with a fixed endpoint for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially, it could work with just a DDNS record if the web server allows this. You could configure the web server with a domain name in the access list. When you log in, it looks up the IP address of your domain, sees traffic coming from that IP address, and you're golden.

If not, the easiest way to over come this off the top of my head (assuming you can't just purchase a static IP from your ISP) would be to rent a cheap VPS (such as with Digital Ocean for example) that has a static IP and log in from there.

Comment: And/or use a VPN to connect from your home network to the VPS so it seems that the connection actually comes from the VPS.

Comment: This will only work if they allow hostnames to be whitelisted. If they whitelist IPAdresses, this won't work.

Comment: @LPChip, hence the qualifier "potentially".

Comment: I felt it necessary to make a comment because I think the way you've written it is not clear. someone who doesn't have enough knowledge could interpret that as a way that the DDNS would be reverse resolvable and the IP adress listing is enough.